# how to sort data depending on a condition in the previous trial in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
choice                      outcome
1                           correct
2                           incorrect
2                           correct
2                           correct
1                           no response
1                           incorrect  
2                           correct
2                           incorrect
```

I have a data frame with many different columns, the ones that I am interested in for this purpose are these two.

I want to see, how many times the choice was 1 and the outcome was correct , and in the immediately next trial (only looking at the trials in which the prior trial had choice 1 and outcome correct), how many times i) the choice was 1 and outcome was correct and ii) choice was 2 and outcome was incorrect

For looking at how many times the choice was 1 and the outcome was correct, I have this line of code and it works. However how do I proceed after this

```
Import os
From scipy.io import load mat
From pandas import DataFrame as df
Import numpy as np
a= loadmat (rat.mat)
b= a[‘all events’]
c= [] 
d=df(c)
correct_1 = d.outcome[(d.outcome =='correct') & (d.choice== 1)].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're saying correctly, the below should do it:

```
correct_2 = d.outcome[((d.outcome =='correct') & (d.choice== 1)) | ((d.outcome =='incorrect') & (d.choice== 2))].count()
```

If you just want a count for choice = 2 and outcome = incorrect, then the code is identical to what you wrote before:

```
correct_2 = d.outcome[(d.outcome =='incorrect') & (d.choice== 2)].count()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following slightly abbreviated version of your dataframe:

```
choice = [1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2]
outcome = ['c','i','c','c','nr','i','c','i']
df = pd.DataFrame({'choice':choice, 'outcome':outcome})
```

Add columns that reflect the previous choice and outcome

```
for c in ['choice', 'outcome']:
    df['prev_' + c] = df[c].shift(1)
```

> I want to see, how many times the choice was 1 and the outcome was correct

```
sum((df.choice == 1) & (df.outcome == 'c'))
```

> and in the immediately next trial

```
df_next = df[(df.prev_choice == 1) & (df.prev_outcome == 'c')]
```

> i) the choice was 1 and outcome was correct

```
sum((df_next.choice == 1) & (df_next.outcome == 'c'))
```

> and ii) choice was 2 and outcome was incorrect

```
sum((df_next.choice == 2) & (df_next.outcome == 'i'))
```